# Java- select a node by inner text

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am converting code from c# to java.

I have the following xml structure:

```
<Foo>

<Son>

<Id>xxx</Id>

</Son>

... more sons

</Foo>
```

I need to select nodes according to the Id value(can be more than one.

I have this line in c#:

```
XmlNodeList res=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("descendant::Son[Id='xxx']");
```

I tried to convert it to the following:

```
NodeList res=(NodeList)xPath.evaluate("xpath expr",inputSource,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

However, I didn't manage to write the right XPath expression.

Any help?

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not at my development machine, but having used XPath in the past, this pops into mind:

```
xPath.evaluate("/Foo/Son[Id='xxx']",...)
```

Also, it's helpful in your question to mention *what you've tried*, and how the results differ from your target output.